# Datadog integration with NGiNX

Tags: nginx, integration, datadog

I am new to Datadog and NGiNX.  I noticed when I was creating a monitor for some integrations several of the integrations were labeled as misconfigured.  My guess is someone clicked the install button but did finish the remaining integration steps.   I started to work with NGiNX and quickly hit a roadblock.

I verified it is running http status module

```
$ nginx -V 2>&1| grep -o http_stub_status_module
http_stub_status_module
```

The NGiNX install is under a different directory than is usual
and the configuration file is under

```
/<dir>/parts/nginx/conf
```

I created the status.conf file there.

When I reload the NGINX I get a failure.  I don't understand what it means or how to proceed from here.

```
nginx: [error] open() "/<dir>/parts/nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

There is a logs directory with nothing in it.

ps -ef|grep nginx

```
    user    35958  88952  0 May24 ?        00:00:43 nginx: worker process
    user    35959  88952  0 May24 ?        00:00:48 nginx: worker process
    root      88952      1  0 Feb21 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process <dir>/parts/nginx/sbin/nginx -c <dir>/etc/nginx/balancer.conf -g pid <dir>/var/nginx-balancer.pid; lock_file /<dir>/var/nginx-balancer.lock; error_log <dir>/var/logs/nginx-balancer-error.log;
    user    109169  63043  0 13:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

I think the issue is that our install doesn't seem to be following the same defaults as the instructions and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this correctly.

If anyone has any insights that would be great!

Chris